# "Error in Display Ticket Sql" why this happen?

Tags: mysql

```html
        <?php
 
 include("Connection.php");
 include("ValidateStaffMessage.php");
 
 
 //getting values
 $ticketID = $_GET['id'];


 
 //select ticket with that id and referred staff email
 $sql_sel = "
SELECT * 
  FROM ticket 
 WHERE referedstaff2 LIKE '%$id%' 
    OR referedstaff1 LIKE '%$id%' 
    OR referedstaff3 LIKE '%$id%' 
    OR referedstaff4 LIKE '%$id%' 
   AND ticketid = '$ticketID'
 ";

 
 $query_sel = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_sel) or die ("Error in Display Ticket Sql." .mysqli_error($connection));
 
 if($query_sel)
 {
  echo "<h3 class=ta__center> Ticket Details: $ticketID </h3>";
     echo "<div class=ta__left><a href=ReferTicket.php><img src=css/images/back.png></a></div><p>&nbsp;</p>";
   
   
   while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query_sel))
       {
     $ticketID   = $fetch[1];
     $name    = $fetch[2];
     $email    = $fetch[3];
     $location   = $fetch[4];
     $category   = $fetch[6];
     $subject    = $fetch[7];
     $summary    = $fetch[8];
     $status    = $fetch[9];
     $dateCreated   = $fetch[10];
     $dateClosed   = $fetch[11];

     $referedstaff1  = $fetch[16];
     $referedstaff2  = $fetch[17];
     $referedstaff3  = $fetch[18];
     $referedstaff4  = $fetch[19];

     $assignedTo   = $fetch[13];
     $progress   = $fetch[14];
   
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
   $displayTimeCreate = date("d/m/Y, g:i:s A",$dateCreated);
   $displayTimeClosed = date("d/m/Y, g:i:s A",$dateClosed);
    }
 }
 else
 echo "Display Failed.";      
 ?>
```

and this error keep coming. Idont whats wrong

"Error in Display Ticket Sql.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''SF000023''' at line 1"

Comment: What is `$id`? Is it a variable defined somewhere in your code?

Comment: yes for session get id  <?php 
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION["CurrentStaff"]))
   {
    $id=$_SESSION["CurrentStaff"];
?>

Comment: Without parentheses, your ORs and ANDs are unclear

Comment: what do you mean or and and about the parentheses? Im sorry i new to mysql